# Update column in Amazon Redshift with join for big tables

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, sql-update, amazon-redshift, database-performance

I have 500M rows with 30 columns table (with bigint ID column), lets call it `big_one`.
Also, I have another one table `extra_one` with the same number of rows and the same ID column, but two new columns with extra data that I'd like to include in the first table.
I added two extra columns into the first table and want to update the data based on join.

Query is quite easy:

```
update big_one set
    col1=extra_one.col1,
    col2=extra_one.col2
from extra_one
where big_one.id=extra_one.id;
```

But during execution the disk space usage dramatically increased up to 100%. Before the start I had 23.41% of free space on 4 nodes (160GB each, 640GB total). The `big_one` table initially used about 18% of space. This 23.41% indicates that I had about 490GB of free disk space to perform updates smoothly. But Redhisft thinks differently.

[image: disk space usage]

Two new columns are md5 hashes (so they're 32 chars length) (ideally it should take up to 16GB of space).

Recap:

1. I have a wide table `big_one`.
2. Have another table `extra_one` (with 3 columns total), with same IDs and number of records.
3. I added two new columns to `big_one`.
4. I want to enrich `big_one` with data from `extra_one`. (into that 2 new columns)

**Q1:** Any advice on how to perform such big updates?

**Q2:** If I will create the VIEW where will join two tables and then use it, will it save me from such space drain situations? How does Redshift work with VIEWs (not materialized) in such cases.

Comment: what/where is aviary_ids? how big (rows & bytes) are big_one and extra_one? are the id's unique? what is the sort/dist key? have you vacuumed and analyzed both tables prior to running this?

Comment: @JonScott fixed. It should be extra_one.

Comment: @JonScott Both have id column of bigint type. And yes, this column is unique (and the same for both tables.)
Have done vacuum full before run it. Haven't ran 'analyze'. Tables without sortkey/distkey, both create from "create table {TABLENAME} as select ..."

Comment: I think as you are updating each row it is moving that to the end of the table. thus creating your issue.
can you split the update (10 x 1/10th?) or can you create/add some more space?

Comment: @JonScott, yes, by updating cluster to 8 nodes (1280GB) it took up to 75% of all capacity to perform it. But why? It's a huge overhead. How I can improve that?

Comment: I've added "Recap" section in question body.

Comment: It might be something related to how Redshift distributes data and exchanges with rows during update. I recomend to try: 1) use ID in both tables as distribution key 2) add unique constraint on both table ID columns 3) use compression on both table col1&2 4) make sure you have defined correct column length for md5 hash storing - varchar(32).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `UPDATE` on a large number of rows.

When a row is modified in Amazon Redshift, the existing row is marked as *Deleted* and a new row is appended to the table. This will effectively double the size of the table and wastes a lot of disk space until the table is Vacuumed. It is also very slow!

Instead:

- Create a query that **JOINs** the two tables
- Use the query to **populate a new table** (see below)
- Delete the old table and **rename the new table** so that it replaces the original table (or, truncate the original table and copy the data back into it)

You can use `CREATE TABLE LIKE` to create a new, empty table based on an existing table.

From [CREATE TABLE - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_TABLE_NEW.html):

> `LIKE parent_table [ { INCLUDING | EXCLUDING } DEFAULTS ]`
>   A clause that specifies an existing table from which the new table automatically copies column names, data types, and NOT NULL constraints. The new table and the parent table are decoupled, and any changes made to the parent table aren't applied to the new table. Default expressions for the copied column definitions are copied only if INCLUDING DEFAULTS is specified. The default behavior is to exclude default expressions, so that all columns of the new table have null defaults.
>
> Tables created with the LIKE option don't inherit primary and foreign key constraints. Distribution style, sort keys,BACKUP, and NULL properties are inherited by LIKE tables, but you can't explicitly set them in the CREATE TABLE ... LIKE statement.